# SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER should be ON when inserting a record

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am stuck in a rather strange problem with SQL Server 2005, which throws

> "SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER should be on when inserting record"

(using as SP) to the particular table. This worked fine earlier but is throwing this error randomly.

I have verified the SP. We didn't manually specify SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER settings inside, so it must be ON by default.

Can someone clarify what could be the problem?

The table must be created with SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER ON right? I didn't check the table script yet.

I have observed that this problem only occur with the SPs doing insert or update on a date column (modifiedAt)... A sample value is '2009-08-10 06:43:59:447'..

Is there a problem with the values passed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After a long struggle we were able to fix this problem. I just wanted to share the reason.

Our build team maintains a separate in-house tool to deploy scripts, which internally triggers the **SQLCMD** (shell) utility to execute T-SQL scripts in a db.

Here is the culprit: **by default, `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `OFF` when running in SQLCMD mode!**

Every script run through this tool is created with `QUOTED IDENTIFIER OFF`. We are the only module which uses indexed views. All the remaining stories you know well in my previous posts :(

NOTE:  I am going to vote everyone's post as useful.

Comment: You just saved me at least an hour of hunting around --- i wouldn't have guessed that SQLCMD was setting this off.  Thanks for adding this clarification

Comment: great... i struggled with this problem for nealry a week.. its a goddamn simple mistake..  i thought this could be useful for someone.. am very glad it helped you... :)

Comment: Ditto on @Ralph Shillington's comments.

Comment: Ran into exactly this problem and it was driving me insane - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  FWIW passing **-I** to SQLCMD will change this option.  Even so, I think I'll switch to using square brackets in my identifiers instead!

Answer (score 5):

Script the stored proc, ensure/change SET options, run the ALTER PROC to ensure SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER ON is set.

**Why?**

The setting of "SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER" is defined at creation time for stored procs and is always "ON" for tables. [Source, BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393(SQL.90).aspx).

> When a table is created, the QUOTED
>   IDENTIFIER option is always stored as
>   ON in the table's metadata even if the
>   option is set to OFF when the table is
>   created.
>
> When a stored procedure is created,
>   the SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER and SET
>   ANSI_NULLS settings are captured and
>   used for subsequent invocations of
>   that stored procedure.

The default for connections can be defined at the server level (sp_configure 'user options') or database level (ALTER DATABASE). For SSMS, it's under "Tools..Options.. Query Execution..SQL Server..ANSI". It's also the default for client libraries too (except DB-LIb).

Now, it you open an SSMS Query Window and start typing "CREATE PROC.." then it uses SSMS settings when you run the code.

And SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER ***can not*** be set at run time inside the stored proc. Show me the a reference before you disagree... From the MS BOL link above:

> When executed inside a stored
>   procedure, the setting of SET
>   QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is not changed.

You have to work hard to run any code with this OFF... so the most likely fix is to ALTER or re-create the stored proc.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2005, SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER is OFF by default, not ON (unless using an ODBC or OLE connection...see [this](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/set-set_30.htm) for more information).

You do not need to create the table with SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER ON to use it.

All you need to do is add SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER ON to the beginning of your SP to enable it for the run of the procedure (and make sure that if you don't wish to leave it on, you have SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER OFF to switch it back).

**EDIT**

I stand corrected. According to this [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393(SQL.90).aspx), SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER is ON by default (unless connection with a DB-Library application.

Comment: i was referring this page... 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393(SQL.90).aspx.. it says on by dafault..

Comment: actually we dint enforce SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER ON in any of ur SPs. all the sps in the db creatd in that way.. only the particular insert sp on the particular table throws this error... 

we could easily solve this if this occurs always... its deployed a week ago, it was working fine till today.. and suddenly giving this problem.. any idea why this behave like this...

Comment: Make sure you're not dynamically building any SQL queries in the stored procedure. That could lead to some data the user entered with double quotes to be built into the query. When SQL Server tries to execute the query...you'd get that error.

Answer (score 1):

I was just reading this article by Erland Sommarskog, [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#quotestring), and it includes the following paragraph in regards to the SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER setting:

> The default for this
>   setting depends on context, but the
>   preferred setting is ON, and it must
>   be ON in order to use XQuery, indexed
>   views and indexes on computed columns.

Does your stored procedure make use of XQuery, indexed views or indexes on computed columns at all?

Comment: thanks for the reply Amal, we dint use any fancy XQuery or other features.. its just a plain insert & update sp..

and it doesnt have any indexed views too...