# way to retrieve the objects QUOTED_IDENTIFIER (and associated ANSI) settings?

Tags: sql-server

is there a way to identify whether the object is created with SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on or off?? (not only this set option, am lookin for a script to identify all the ANSI settings associated to the object)

this is a follow up to the questions in staack [link - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137821/problem-with-set-quoted-identifier) and [Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243991/update-failed-because-the-following-set-options-have-incorrect-settings-quoted/1244326#1244326)

i ve been getting the SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  error  on a single table (which got indexed view). I have verified all the settings, scripts are fine. and it created perfectly with correct settings.

It gives the error all of a sudden after applying some db fixes (not our script)..

**Note**: sorry to open a new thread, i dint get any possible solution to my first [link - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137821/problem-with-set-quoted-identifier) thread, thought its dead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For code and check constraints:

```
SELECT 
    OBJECTPROPERTYEX (OBJECT_ID('MyProc'), 'ExecIsQuotedIdentOn')
    OBJECTPROPERTYEX (OBJECT_ID('MyCK'), 'IsQuotedIdentOn')
```

I can't find anything for tables/indexes in system views or functions.

Comment: When a table is created, the QUOTED IDENTIFIER option is always stored as ON in the table's metadata even if the option is set to OFF when the table is created.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    'Object created with dangerous SET Option' [Finding]
    ,o.[type_desc] [Type]
    ,QUOTENAME( SCHEMA_NAME( o.[schema_id] ) ) [Schema]
    ,QUOTENAME( OBJECT_NAME( sm.[object_id] ) ) [Name]
    ,sm.[uses_ansi_nulls] [ANSI NULL]
    ,sm.[uses_quoted_identifier] [QUOTED]
    ,sm.[definition]
from [sys].[sql_modules] sm
join [sys].[objects] o on o.[object_id] = sm.[object_id]
    and (
        sm.[uses_ansi_nulls] != 1
        or sm.[uses_quoted_identifier] != 1
        )
    and o.[is_ms_shipped] = 0;
```