# Schedule SQL query ERROR -Set QUOTED IDENTIFIER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried to schedule an sql query it failed,and the error that I got was,

```
Update failed because the following SET have incorrect settings:'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET Options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or xml data type methods and/or spatial index operations.[SQLSTATE 42000](Error 1934).
```

I have this solution

```
Add SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
before your UPDATE statements in SQL Job step.
```

But, what does `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` do ?
Could someone explain it to me?

Thanks

EDIT 1;
I tried the above , the scheduled query executed , but did not change an of the fields anything?

The Query is use;

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
update dbo.myTable
set name=[dbo].[functName](name);
```

If I run a normal `UPDATE` query ,

`update dbo.myTable
    set name=[dbo].[functName](name);`

It works, and fields are changed.

Why would it not work in the scheduled query?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED\_IDENTIFIER'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243991/update-failed-because-the-following-set-options-have-incorrect-settings-quoted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It specifies how SQL Server will be treating your data which you have defined in Single Quotes and Double Quotes. The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) gives you the answer:

> Causes SQL Server to follow the ISO rules regarding quotation mark
>   delimiting identifiers and literal strings. Identifiers delimited by
>   double quotation marks can be either Transact-SQL reserved keywords or
>   can contain characters not generally allowed by the Transact-SQL
>   syntax rules for identifiers.

Also check the **Remarks** section which provides the details about ON and OFF.

> When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON, identifiers can be delimited by
>   double quotation marks, and literals must be delimited by single
>   quotation marks. When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF, identifiers cannot
>   be quoted and must follow all Transact-SQL rules for identifiers. For
>   more information, see Database Identifiers. Literals can be delimited
>   by either single or double quotation marks................

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.