# SQL Server QUOTED_IDENTIFIER Error On UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following error on a very basic update query when it is executed as job in SQL Server 2008.  It runs as expected when I run it manually in SSMS.  Can somebody help me figure out what is going on to cause this?  The database settings have Quoted Identifiers Enabled set to False.  I have tried adding SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS TRUE to the job and that did not work either.

> *UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for
>   use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or
>   filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type
>   methods and/or spatial index operations.*

The query is as follows (table and column names have been changed to protect the innocent)

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = 'C'
WHERE col_status = 'A' AND emp_number
IN (SELECT emp_number
FROM Table2
WHERE emp_status = 'T')
```

Comment: Check this post, and check if you have triggers on the updating table https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523803/4608204

Answer (score 1):

You need add below two set statements while updating table1.

You can use join directly to update table1.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

UPDATE T1
SET T1.Column1 = 'C'
FROM Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T2.emp_number = T1.emp_number
AND T1.col_status = 'A'
AND T2.emp_status = 'T';

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
```