# ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER killed things. What are they for?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

NOTE: I checked [Understanding QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481441/understanding-quoted-identifier) and it does not answer my question.

I got my DBAs to run an index I made on my Prod servers (they looked it over and approved it).

It sped up my queries just like I wanted.  However, I started getting errors like this:

> [image: UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: ANSI_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NUL]

As a developer I have usually ignored these settings.  And it has never mattered. (For 9+ years).  Well, today it matters.

I went and looked at one of the sprocs that are failing and it has this before the create for the sproc:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

**Can anyone tell me from a application developer point of view what these set statements do?**  (Just adding the above code before my index create statements did not fix the problem.)

NOTE: Here is an example of what my indexes looked like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_ClientFilerTo0]
ON [ClientTable] ([Client])
INCLUDE ([ClientCol1],[ClientCol2],[ClientCol3] ... Many more columns)
WHERE Client = 0


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Client_Status]
ON [OrderTable] ([Client],[Status])
INCLUDE ([OrderCol1],[OrderCol2],[OrderCol3],[OrderCol4])
WHERE [Status] <= 7
GO
```

Comment: You are missing the `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` setting. You also appear to have a corrupted error message string in your screenshot, which suggest that there may be deeper problems in you application.

Comment: @RBarryYoung But when I added the two to the index create, the first two were still in the error message...  (And they are not on the sproc...)  Still I will try it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - tried it what that setting and it still fails. (Same error message.)

Comment: That takes me back to the question of possible corruption in your application binaries and/or you system's DLLS. (Or your SQL Server's DLLs)

Comment: @RBarryYoung - This question was more focused on what these settings do.  I am going to create a new one for how to fix this...

Comment: @Vaccano:- Sir, the possible guess made by RBarryYoung seems to be write. I also faced the same problem few months back. And the problem was resolved after I found that some of my system dlls were corrupt due to which I faced this issue!

Comment: @RahulTripathi - I appreciate that idea, but this error is happening on two completely different SQL Servers and on many many user's machines.  It seems too unlikely that it is random DLL Corruption.

Comment: @Vaccano:- Well a small query? Is this error coming after executing every query or stored procedure or is it coming in any specific scenario? Also needless to say that you must have made all the stored procedures with Setting ON!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

OK, from an application developer's point of view, here's what these settings do:

### QUOTED_IDENTIFIER

This setting controls how quotation marks `".."` are interpreted by the SQL compiler.  When `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is ON then quotes are treated like brackets (`[...]`) and can be used to quote SQL object names like table names, column names, etc.  When it is OFF (not recommended), then quotes are treated like apostrophes (`'..'`) and can be used to quote text strings in SQL commands.

### ANSI_NULLS

This setting controls what happens when you try to use any comparison operator other than `IS` on NULL.  When it is ON, these comparisons follow the standard which says that comparing to NULL always fails (because it isn't a value, it's a Flag) and returns `FALSE`.  When this setting is OFF (really ***not*** recommended) you can sucessfully treat it like a value and use `=`, `<>`, etc. on it and get back TRUE as appropiate.

The proper way to handle this is to instead use the `IS` (`ColumnValue IS NULL ..`).

### CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL

This setting controls whether NULLs "Propogate" whn used in string expressions.  When this setting is ON, it follows the standard and an expression like `'some string' + NULL ..` always returns NULL.  Thus, in a series of string concatenations, one NULL can cause the whole expression to return NULL.  Turning this OFF (also, not recommended) will cause the NULLs to be treated like empty strings instead, so `'some string' + NULL` just evaluates to `'some string'`.

The proper way to handle this is with the COALESCE (or ISNULL) function: `'some string' + COALESCE(NULL, '') ..`.

Answer (score 36):

I find [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql), [blog posts](http://ranjithk.com/2010/01/10/understanding-set-quoted_identifier-onoff/), [Stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481441/understanding-quoted-identifier) unhelpful in explaining what turning on `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` means.

### Olden times

Originally, SQL Server allowed you to use **quotation marks** (`"..."`) and **apostrophes** (`'...'`) around strings interchangeably (like Javascript does):

- `SELECT "Hello, world!"` *--quotation mark*
- `SELECT 'Hello, world!'` *--apostrophe*

And if you wanted to name a table, view, stored procedure, column etc with something that would otherwise violate all the rules of naming objects, you could wrap it in **square brackets** (`[`, `]`):

```
CREATE TABLE [The world's most awful table name] (
   [Hello, world!] int
)

SELECT [Hello, world!] FROM [The world's most awful table name]
```

And that all worked, and made sense.

### Then came ANSI

Then ANSI came along, and they had other ideas:

- use **apostrophe** (`'...'`) for strings
- if you have a funky name, wrap it in **quotation marks** (`"..."`)
- and we don't even care about your square brackets

Which means that if you wanted to *"quote"* a funky column or table name you must use quotation marks:

```
SELECT "Hello, world!" FROM "The world's most awful table name"
```

If you knew SQL Server, you knew that **quotation marks** were already being used to represent strings. If you blindly tried to execute that *ANSI-SQL* as if it were *T-SQL*, it is nonsense:

```
SELECT 'Hello, world!' FROM 'The world''s most awful table name'
```

and SQL Server tells you so:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'The world's most awful table name'.
```

### You must opt-in to the new ANSI behavior

So Microsoft added a feature to let you opt-in to the ANSI flavor of SQL.

**Original** *(aka SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF)*

```
SELECT "Hello, world!" --valid
SELECT 'Hello, world!' --valid
```

**SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON**

```
SELECT "Hello, world!" --INVALID
SELECT 'Hello, world!' --valid
```

These days everyone has `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS ON`, which technically means you should be using `quotes` rather than `square brackets` around identifiers:

**T-SQL (bad?)** *(e.g. SQL generated by Entity Framework)*

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Customers]
SET [FirstName] = N'Ian'
WHERE [CustomerID] = 7
```

**ANSI-SQL (good?)**

```
UPDATE "dbo"."Customers"
SET "FirstName" = N'Ian'
WHERE "CustomerID" = 7
```

In reality nobody in the SQL Server universe uses U+0022 QUOTATION MARK <kbd>"</kbd> to wrap identifiers. We all continue to use <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>.

Comment: Totally appreciate understanding the history behind why MS uses square brackets. Upvote.

Answer (score 8):

I think while rebuilding the indexes it got turned off.

Do check the **[SET Options with their setting values required while working with filtered index](http://sqlhints.com/2012/05/12/set-options-with-their-setting-values-required-while-working-with-filtered-index/)**

You need to turn On the below setting while dealing with filtered index:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

You need add to add

```
SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

for all my stored procedures editing a table with a computed column to avoid that error.

**[ANSI_NULLS:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)**

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, a SELECT statement that uses WHERE
>   column_name = NULL returns zero rows even if there are null values in
>   column_name. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <> NULL
>   returns zero rows even if there are nonnull values in column_name.
>
> When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, the Equals (=) and Not Equal To (<>)
>   comparison operators do not follow the ISO standard. A SELECT
>   statement that uses WHERE column_name = NULL returns the rows that
>   have null values in column_name. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE
>   column_name <> NULL returns the rows that have nonnull values in the
>   column. Also, a SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <>
>   XYZ_value returns all rows that are not XYZ_value and that are not
>   NULL.

**[QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx)**

> When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON, identifiers can be delimited by
>   double quotation marks, and literals must be delimited by single
>   quotation marks. When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF, identifiers cannot
>   be quoted and must follow all Transact-SQL rules for identifiers. For
>   more information, see Database Identifiers. Literals can be delimited
>   by either single or double quotation marks.
>
> When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON (default), all strings delimited by
>   double quotation marks are interpreted as object identifiers.
>   Therefore, quoted identifiers do not have to follow the Transact-SQL
>   rules for identifiers. They can be reserved keywords and can include
>   characters not generally allowed in Transact-SQL identifiers. Double
>   quotation marks cannot be used to delimit literal string expressions;
>   single quotation marks must be used to enclose literal strings. If a
>   single quotation mark (') is part of the literal string, it can be
>   represented by two single quotation marks ("). SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
>   must be ON when reserved keywords are used for object names in the
>   database.

**[CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx)**

> When SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is ON, concatenating a null value
>   with a string yields a NULL result. For example, SELECT 'abc' + NULL
>   yields NULL. When SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is OFF, concatenating a
>   null value with a string yields the string itself (the null value is
>   treated as an empty string). For example, SELECT 'abc' + NULL yields
>   abc.
>
> If SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is not specified, the setting of the
>   CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL database option applies.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI_NULLS ON makes any binary boolean expression with a null value evaluate to false.  Using the following template:

```
declare @varA, @varB int

if <binary boolean expression>
begin
    print 'true'
end
else
begin
    print 'false'
end


@varA: NULL; @varB: NULL; @varA = @varB evaluates to false
@varA: 1; @varB: NULL; @varA <> @varB evaluates to false
```

The proper way to test for null is to use `is [not] NULL`

```
@varA: NULL; @varA is NULL evaluates to true
@varA: 1; @varA is not NULL evaluates to true
```

QUOTED_IDENTIFER ON merely allows you to use double quotes to delimit identifiers (bad idea IMO, just user square brackets)

```
from tblA "a" -- ok when ON, not ok when OFF
from tblA [a] -- always ok
```

Comment: QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON makes SQL Server follow ISO standards for delimiting identifiers. It's _not_ a bad idea, it's a _standard_ - ignoring it is a poor recommendation. It's certainly more sensible than quoting with brackets.

Comment: _"ANSI_NULLS ON makes any binary boolean expression with a null value evaluate to false."_ No, it doesn't. It makes any comparison involving a `null` evaluate to a third, **unknown** state and therefore be untestable. We can't say `declare @str varchar(10) = null; if not (@str = 'dennis') print 'hi';`, which is the claim you're making.