# Will you help me find the I cannot seem to cast as integer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, column-alias

All I am trying to do is pull the most recent '`Scan`' (hence 'LastScan') from each '`location`' and then find out if any of them are 2 hours or more '`old`'(which would make them overdue).

```
Select cast(max(entered_date) as int) as 'LastScan', location
FROM housing_activity
WHERE 'LastScan' <= Datediff(HH,-2,GETDATE())
Group by location
```

This is my error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'LastScan' to data type int.
```

Comment: In SqlServer, you should quote identifiers in `[ ]`, or possibly double quotes (`" "`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45865263/121309

Comment: *Never* use single quotes for column names.  You are making a mistake that should never happen (if you make that change, you'll get another error that `LastScan` is unknown, but at least that would make sense).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
; WITH cte AS (
SELECT
  location
  , LastScan = entered_date
  , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY entered_date DESC)
FROM housing_activity 
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM cte
WHERE 
   RN = 1
   AND LastScan <= DateAdd(hour,-2,GETDATE())
```

Comment: **Thank you for all of the help!**
I had no idea about the single quotes.  (Embarrassed) HUGE help.

  I used CTE and it pulls exactly the values that I need.
When I copy the code into my stored procedure and save it, I have no problem.
When I execute it, the error I get appears to come from when I try to insert into a table to send by email.  
Does something stand out as incorrect?  I have searched @mail_body and cannot find an answer.

THE ERROR--Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: You need to ask that as a new question and provide more details.