# How to find diff between two strings in SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-server-2008, t-sql, split

I have two strings, I want to get difference between contents of two strings in SQL ??

for example,

```
Declare @String1 as varchar(100)='a,b,c,d,e';

Declare @String2 as varchar(100)='b,e';
```

Now i want difference between two strings as "a,c,d"

Comment: Comma separated values and SQL don't go well together...

Comment: I agree, you're going to want to split these strings out into their components and then do something like a full outer join

Comment: Is the answer you expect only related to the values between commas? Because if you strip out of String1, values in String2, you'd get 'a,c,d,' (so with the last comma)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both strings must be split into their parts. In SQL-Server 2008 this is best to be done with an XML approach.

**attention**: If your data might include forbidden characters like `<>öä@€&` and not just plain latin characters like in your example, you'd need some extra effort...

The rest is fairly easy: Just take all parts of `@String1` which are not found in `@String2`.

The concatenated result is - again - best to be done via XML

Try this:

```
Declare @String1 as varchar(100)='a,b,c,d,e';

Declare @String2 as varchar(100)='b,e';

WITH FirstStringSplit(S1) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@String1,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
)
,SecondStringSplit(S2) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@String2,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
)

SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',' + part1.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM FirstStringSplit
    CROSS APPLY S1.nodes('/x') AS A(part1)
    WHERE part1.value('.','nvarchar(max)') NOT IN(SELECT B.part2.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                                                  FROM SecondStringSplit 
                                                  CROSS APPLY S2.nodes('/x') AS B(part2)
                                                  ) 
    FOR XML PATH('')

),1,1,'')
```

Comment: The Next error is raised: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.(42000,1934)

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader, what's the problem here? Did you try to set this `ON`? You might [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1137821/5089204).  Especially with older databases which were upgrade with scripts over a long periode, you might have problems with the default settings of some options which where nevere upgraded to the *modern* values...

Comment: You are right, after setting QUOTED_IDENTIFIER equals ON, everything is okay. thanks bro. voted it up :)

Comment: I created a function using this answer and it worked great!

Comment: @thecoolmacdude, these days you'd be better off with string_split() or a json based splitter.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting task, Is it business requirement or what else?

```
Declare @String1 as varchar(100)='a,b,c,d,e';
 SET @String1=REPLACE(@String1,',','')

Declare @String2 as varchar(100)='b,e';
SET @String2=REPLACE(@String2,',','')

;WITH StringOne AS (

     SELECT CAST('' AS VARCHAR(1)) AS ch, 1 as cnt
     UNION ALL
     SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@String1,cnt,1) AS VARCHAR(1)) AS ch, cnt+1 as cnt
     FROM StringOne 
     WHERE cnt <= LEN(@String1)
),StringTwo AS (

 SELECT CAST('' AS VARCHAR(1)) AS ch, 1 as cnt
 UNION ALL
 SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@String2,cnt,1) AS VARCHAR(1)) AS ch, cnt+1 as cnt
 FROM StringTwo 
 WHERE cnt <= LEN(@String2)
),ExceptOperation AS(

  SELECT ch FROM StringOne
  EXCEPT
  SELECT ch FROM StringTwo
)

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ','+ ch FROM ExceptOperation FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

Comment: I like straight approaches. But - to be honest - I'd assume, that `a,b,c` is just an example and one cannot work this down on single letter count... :-) Anyway +1 from my side

Answer (score 1):

Simple Way

```
declare @string1 varchar(max),@string2 varchar(max)
set @string1='Apple, Orange, Banana'
set @string2='Apple, Orange, Banana, Pinapple, Grapes'

select REPLACE(@String2,@string1,'')
```

Result

```
, Pinapple, Grapes
```

Answer (score 0):

First take the function from the following link [Parse comma-separated string to make IN List of strings in the Where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481479/parse-comma-separated-string-to-make-in-list-of-strings-in-the-where-clause)

Then use the following query;

```
Declare @String1 as varchar(100)='a,b,c,d,e';

Declare @String2 as varchar(100)='b,e';

SELECT
    s1.val
    ,s2.val
FROM [dbo].[f_split](@String1,',') s1
FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[f_split](@String2,',') s2
    ON s1.val = s2.val
WHERE s1.val IS NULL
    OR s2.val IS NULL
```

Which will give you the following results;

```
val val
a   NULL
c   NULL
d   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably overkill but I noticed this would only go one direction and not the other.  EG: Variable 2 has adds but ignores if variable 1 does.  I would leverage faking a JSON array using new abilities in SQL 2016 and up utilizing OPENJSON.  You can make this into a reusable function quite easily:

```
DECLARE
    @X VARCHAR(1024) = 'a,b,c'
,   @Y VARCHAR(1024) = 'a,b,d,e'
;

DECLARE 
    @Delimeter VARCHAR(8) = ','  --May use a comma, maybe a ;
,   @AddText VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Added: '  --Choose what to say for adds
,   @RemoveText VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Removed: '  --Choose what to say for removes

--Leave below variables alone as they are used for business logic
,   @ReturnText VARCHAR(MAX) = ''  
,   @Added VARCHAR(MAX)
,   @Removed VARCHAR(MAX)
;

SELECT @X = '["' + REPLACE(@X, '' + @Delimeter + '', '","') + '"]'  --get input ready for JSON 
SELECT @Y = '["' + REPLACE(@Y, '' + @Delimeter + '', '","') + '"]'  --get input ready for JSON 
;

SELECT @Added = STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + v
    from 
        ( SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Value)) AS v FROM OPENJSON(@Y) EXCEPT  SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Value)) FROM OPENJSON(@X)) AS x
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @Removed = STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + v
    from 
        ( SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Value)) AS v FROM OPENJSON(@X) EXCEPT  SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Value)) FROM OPENJSON(@Y)) AS x
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

IF LEN(@Added) > 0
BEGIN
    IF LEN(@AddText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ReturnText += @AddText
    END

    SELECT @ReturnText += @Added
END

IF LEN(@Removed) > 0
BEGIN
    IF LEN(@ReturnText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ReturnText += ' '
    END

    IF LEN(@RemoveText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ReturnText += @RemoveText
    END

    SELECT @ReturnText += @Removed
END

SELECT @ReturnText
```

This will yield:
[image]