# Finding the Differences Between 2 Columns, clarify

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, difference

As stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59457968/finding-the-differences-between-2-columns/63972587#63972587)
Let's say I have data that looks like this:

```
Declare @YourTable table (ColA varchar(150),ColB varchar(150))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('John, Sally','John, Sally, Cindy, Steve')

Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Outer Apply (
               Select Diff=value
                From (
                       Select value=ltrim(rtrim(value)) From string_split(ColA,',')
                       Union All
                       Select value=ltrim(rtrim(value)) From string_split(ColB,',')
                     ) B1
                Group By Value
                Having count(*)=1
             ) B
```

you got

```
ColA                ColB                        Diff
John, Sally         John, Sally, Cindy, Steve   Cindy
John, Sally         John, Sally, Cindy, Steve   Steve
```

but how to get

```
ColA                ColB                        Diff
John, Sally         John, Sally, Cindy, Steve   Cindy, Steve
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is `string_agg()`, which I would put into the `apply` subquery:

```
Select A.*, B.*
 From  @YourTable A Outer Apply
       (select string_agg(diff, ', ') as diff
        from (Select Diff=value
              From (Select value=ltrim(rtrim(value)) From string_split(ColA,',')
                    Union All
                    Select value=ltrim(rtrim(value)) From string_split(ColB,',')
                   ) B1
              Group By Value
              Having count(*)=1
             ) B
       ) B;
```

But I think using a `full join` is simpler:

```
select A.*, B.*
from @YourTable A outer apply
     (select string_agg(coalesce(trim(a.value), trim(b.value)), ', ') as diff
      from string_split(ColA, ',') a full join
           string_split(ColB, ',') b
           on trim(a.value) = trim(b.value)
      where a.value is null or b.value is null
     ) b;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6fb20f61ee6f3f747ced146a82da94b1) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can select from a query and aggregate the result:

```
select cola, colb, string_agg(diff, ', ') as diffs
from ( <your query> ) q
group by cola, colb;
```